# Prove that null $T$ = null $\phi$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional, $T\in\mathscr L(V,W)$, and there exists $\phi\in V'$ such that range $T'$ = span $(\phi)$. Prove that null $T$ = null $\phi$.

I just need some assistance cleaning up my proof and then clarifying what to do at the end.

Let $v\in$ null $T$. Then $T(v)=0$. Since range $T'$ = span $(\phi)$, there exists some $\theta \in W'$ such that $T'(\theta)=\theta T=\phi$. Now, $\phi(v)=\theta T(v)=\theta(0)=0$. Thus, $v\in$ null$\phi$. This implies null $T \subset$ null $\phi$.

I am not sure what to do after this step to finally say that null $T$ = null $\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction that you are missing:

Assume that $v\in null(\phi)$.

Let $w'\in W'$. Then $w'(T(v))=T'(w')(v)$, by definition of $T'$.

Since $\phi$ generates the range of $T'$ we can write $T'(w')$ as $r\phi$.

Therefore, $w'(T(v))=T'(w')(v)=(r\phi)(v)=r\phi(v)=0$.

Since $w'$ was arbitrary, it follows that $T(v)=0$. $\leftarrow$ This simple way to prove that a vector is zero is extremely useful in linear algebra. Keep it always in your head.

This is, $v\in null(T)$.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. How do we know for sure that T(v) = 0 based on the fact that w'T(v) = 0?

Comment: @mmm $w'$ was an arbitrary element of $W'$. If a vector $a$ vanishes on all elements of the dual then it is zero. To prove that, assume that the vector  is non-zero, then define a functional to be equal to $1$ on $a$ and extend the functional from the space generated by $a$ to the whole space by defining it to be zero on any subspace that complements the subspace generated by $a$. That would be a functional that doesn't vanish at $a$. Contradiction with the assumption that all functionals should vanish at $a$.